# not connecting to internet when switch from windos7 to ubuntu after a restart

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, wubi

ihave dual booted ubuntu 12.04 from wubi in window 7. now i am having a critical problem where i cant find any logic to it. when i switch from widows7 to ubuntu after a restart i found my internet connection is no more in ubuntu, now again i have to go to windows7 after restarting from ubuntu and found the net is completely ok in win7, and just again restarting from windows7 to ubuntu it comes back with no problem whatsoever. what is it all about? i have a lan netwok connection which comes directly to my lan port from the hub switch

Answer (score 0):

`rfkill unblock all` in terminal in Ubuntu
should do the trick.

Comment: sorry its failed to connect yet again to linux